# Displaying UIActionSheet on keyWindow fails view != nil assertion

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4, ios5

I have a strange problem,

I am trying to display UIActionSheet on a UIWindow object using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
```

The following code rises `view != nil` assertion failure

```
UIWindow *mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

if(mainWindow != nil)
    [menuUIActionSheet showInView:mainWindow];
```

The above fails under iOS 4.3 and under iOS 5.0 is valid.

> *** Assertion failure in -[UIActionSheet showInView:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UIActionSheet.m:4402
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not
>   satisfying: view != nil'

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to pass a real UIView instance. You could try to use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController.view` instead.

Answer (score 0):

in

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder
```

make the property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)   UIWindow *window;


@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
```

then use

```
AppDelegate.window
```